# Return numeric value from an string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

How can I get the numeric value from an string?
In my case string is `R1350.00` and

Expected output:

```
1350
```

I tried the following:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", 'R1350.00');
```

but I also want to remove the last two string `00`. It is an amount value in ZAR. and I have to store the integer value in my database.

Comment: I'm going to be *that guy* and ask, What Have You Tried?™

Comment: Is the string always going to be in that format? `00` is also numeric - why have you excluded it from the output?

Comment: @AnthonySterling : I tried this one
echo $result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", 'R1350.00');

but i also want to remove the last two string 00. It is an amount value in ZAR. and I have to store the integer value in my database.
I hope you can understand very easily why i am trying like that output.

Comment: @vin: You can use `preg_match('/[A-Z](\d+)\.\d{2}/', $string, $matches);` -- `$matches[1]` will contain the output you need.

Comment: @vin: Or maybe `echo intval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $string));`.

Comment: @AmalMurali: Thanks for your perfect answer. it works perfectly.
Thanks again for correct my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
$string  = "R1350.00";
preg_match("/(\d+\.\d{1,2})/",$string , $number);
echo $number[0];

?>
```

OR if you want to remove the `.00`, use this

```
preg_match("/(\d+)/",$string , $number);
```

Comment: Please explain -1 so that I can correct the answer

Comment: This would match strings like `R1350#00`, too.

Comment: @AmalMurali : I got it, corrected the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: This will capture the entire decimal number, which is not what the OP wants. You need to capture `(\d+)` instead. Also, `preg_match_all` isn't necessary here. [`preg_match()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855093/return-numeric-value-from-an-string-in-php#comment33084683_21855093) will do fine.

Comment: I think he wants entire thing, That is what I understood from his comments, He thanked you for correcting the question :)

Comment: See the "Expected Output" in the question. Also, "but I also want to remove the last two string 00.".

Comment: @AmalMurali : Yes I saw that, I am not arguing, that is what I understood from his comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function and then [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/number_format)

```
$str = 'R1350.00';
$str = str_replace('R',''.$str);
$str = number_format($str,0,'','');
echo $str;
//output 1350
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have a `replace()` function. You probably meant `str_replace()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$str="R1350.00";
$val=explode(".",$str);
echo substr($val[0],1);

//output 1350
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always going to be that format and length, you could use `substr()` like so:

```
$result = substr("R1350.00", 1, -3); // Output: 1350
```

EDIT: If the first character is always R (or a letter, rather) and there's always a decimal place not needed, then you can also use `explode()` on the decimal point and apply a `substr()` again.  Like so:

```
$arrResult = explode(".", $result);
$strResult = substr($arrResult[0], 1); // Output: 1350
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my value is variable it can be change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to achieve that.  First, replace anything that's not a number or a dot.  That will leave your string with `1350.00`.  Then, just add zero to the number to make it an integer - effectively removing the decimal point and trailing zeroes.

```
<?php

$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', 'R1350.00') + 0;
print $result;
```